# Session tracking with cookies turned off and url should not have session id

Tags: struts, sessionid, session-cookies, cookieless

I am working in Struts and jsp. I need to keep my cookies turned off as i need  multi-tab browser support. So a solution is required to hide the session id in the URL and still keep track of the session. Please note that the cookies have to be turned off and the session id has to be avoided in the URL. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The Java Servlet API allows two mechanisms to track sessions: cookies and URL rewriting. You have to pick one or the other.